# How to parseInt or ParseInt embedded data with TypeScript in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, typescript, qualtrics

Even when I save an integer to embedded data earlier in the survey flow (in previous blocks on different screens), I am not able in Javascript to get the embedded data value, ensure it is parsed as a number/integer, then use it in a loop. Is this something about TypeScript? I didn't see anything about parseInt or ParseInt in the TypeScript documentation.

For example, suppose I do the following:

```
// Draw a random number
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

// Save it in embedded data
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData("foo", x);

// In a later block on a different screen, get the embedded data as an integer
var x_new = "${e://Field/foo}"; // not an int
var x_new = parseInt("${e://Field/foo}"); // doesn't work
var x_new = ParseInt("${e://Field/foo}"); // doesn't work

// Loop using x_new:
for(i = 0; i < x_new; i++) {
   console.log(i)
   }
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Perhaps I just don't know how to parseint().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "normal" JS runtime system, we have `parseInt` function, the function gets a string (like number string) as a parameter. In this env, we don't support your syntax - "${e://Field/foo}", because it is not a "number string".

In Qualtrics system environment they have `parseInt` too, but they support their custom syntax `"${e://Field/foo}"` to get `EmbeddedData`.

Make sure that your code is running on [Qualtrics system environment](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/question-options/add-javascript/).

Comment: Yes, the goal is to take the value saved in the foo embedded data field and use it in the Javascript as a number.  My understanding is var x = "${e://Field/foo}" assigns that value to x as a string. Since I wish to later run tests, loops, etc. using this value as a number, I used parseInt. It doesn't appear to produce a number and x is not already a number.

Answer (score 1):

ParseInt is just turning your string into an integer.
Look at the demo below.

```js
let myVar = "${e://Field/foo}"; // This is a string
console.log(myVar); // This prints a string
console.log(parseInt(myVar)); // This prints "NaN", i.e. Not a Number, because the string isn't a representation of a number.
```

Comment: Hm. So is this as simple as dropping the quotation marks? I don't think that works in Qualtrics either.

Comment: Try `console.log()`ing your variables. I'm pretty sure this line `var x_new = "${e://Field/foo}";` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Regardless of what Qualtrics is doing, these are the correct steps to debug your issue.

I'm fairly certain the x_new variable isn't what you think it is, otherwise `parseInt()` would give you the int you're after.